# Multithreading to parse stream of data from multiple files

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have an python program which parse the stream of data as shown below

```
tail -F /path1/restapi.log -F /path2/restapi.log | parse.py
```

parse.py is parsing data from sys.stdin.readline

```
import re
import sys
import json

def deep_get(dictionary, keys, default=None):
    return reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key, default) if isinstance(d, dict) else default, keys.split("."), dictionary)

regexp_date_status = re.compile(r'(\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+.\d+\+\d+) (\w+)')

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if re.search(r'Request #\d+: {', line):
        date_status = regexp_date_status.match(line)
        json_str = '{\n'
        while True:
            json_str += sys.stdin.readline()
            try:
                d = json.loads(json_str) # we have our dictionary, perhaps
            except Exception:
                pass
            else:
                username = (deep_get(d,"context.authorization.authUserName", default="Username not found"))
                hostname = (deep_get(d,"context.headers.X-Forwarded-For"))
                uri      = (deep_get(d,"context.uri"))
                verb     = (deep_get(d,"context.verb"))

                print("State->{} : Date->{} : User->{} : Host->{} : URI->{} : Verb->{}".format(date_status.group(2), date_status.group(1), username,hostname,uri,verb))

                break
```

I would like to do multithreading as number of files can increase upto 30

```
tail -F /path1/restapi.log -F /path2/restapi.log /path3/restapi.log -F /path4/restapi.log .... | parse.py
```

How do I divide the work among the threads in this case as data is streamed and parsed until I get the valid dictionary in try block ? also do I need to leverage Queues here ?

Answer (score 0):

Let bash deal with the multiple instances of parse.py.
Something similar to:

```
echo -e 'file1.log\nfile2.log\nfile3.log'| xargs -n 1 --max-procs 10 -I % sh -c 'tail -f % |parse.py'
```

xargs will handle things in multiple instances.

Note the '\n' in the files list.

Example to play round with:

```
echo -e "hello\nto\nyou" |xargs -n 1 --max-procs 2 -I % sh -c 'sleep 3; echo %'
```

This will use two threads to do the sleep and echo.
The result will be 'hello' and 'to' with a delay before 'you' is seen.